# Grouping select data together

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find a way to group together my data from my select query. So I am outputting data of which members belong to which team but it just pushed it out all sepereatly so for instance it will be `team1 - member1`, `team 2 - member2` & `team1 - member3` all in 3 rows where I need it to be `team1 - member1, member3` & `team2 - member 2`

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT t.team_id, t.team_name, m.member_id, m.member_name 
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN team_members tm on t.team_id = tm.team_id
LEFT JOIN members m on m.member_id = tm.member_id;
";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            echo 'team: <strong>' . $row["team_name"] . '</strong><br>';
            echo 'member: <strong>' . $row["member_name"] . '</strong><br><br>';

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to first order the results by team_name.

```
SELECT t.team_id, t.team_name, m.member_id, m.member_name 
FROM teams t
LEFT JOIN team_members tm on t.team_id = tm.team_id
LEFT JOIN members m on m.member_id = tm.member_id
ORDER BY t.team_name ASC
```

And in the loop check if the team is different from the last team.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $LastTeam=""; $NumTeamMembers=0;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($LastTeam != $row["team_name"] ){
           $LastTeam=$row["team_name"];
           if ($NumTeamMembers>0)
             echo '</strong><br><br>';
           echo 'team: <strong>' . $row["team_name"] . '</strong><br>';
           $NumTeamMembers=0;
        }
        if ($NumTeamMembers==0)
          echo 'members: <strong> ';
        else
          echo ', ';
        echo  $row["member_name"];
        $NumTeamMembers++;
    }
    echo '</strong><br><br>';
}
```